# Heuristics for maximizing the performance for a given complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, asymptotics

I often have to balance the computational requirement of each qualitatively different module of my algorithm. So, I'm using this heuristics for maximizing the performance for a given complexity, but I couldn't find this heuristics anywhere online. Could anyone give me some reference?

Let $F(x):=\sum_{i=1}^N O(f_i(x))$ be the complexity of my algorithm, where $x=(x_1,\ldots x_k)$, and each $O(f_i(x))$ is the complexity of $i$-th module of algorithm. Note that the algorithm performs better each time we increase the computes for any of the module, i.e., $f_i$, but we don't know how the form of the performance scaling function $G(f_1, f_2,\ldots f_N)$ looks like. I usually set $O(x_i)$ for each $i$ such that $O(f_i(x))=O(f_j(x))$ for any $i,j$. In other words, I usually want each module to spend asymptotically the same computes, so that none of them will become the bottleneck. You can assume each $f_i(x)$ is a polynomial of positive coefficients for simplicity. I think this is kinda common sense. Is there any formal jusitification?